# I want to turn words into codes using lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop

Like the title says, I want to basically create a code generator using lists. What I am currently doing is trying to do it on a small scale with just 1 word.

```
letterlist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101]

name = 'robert'
ii=0
nn = list(name)
code=1
while ii<=len(name)-1:
    for nn in letterlist:
        code *= zip(letterlist,primes)[1]
    ii+=1
print 'robert has a code equal to %f' %code
```

but I get TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'

instead of

```
robert has a code equal to 409760241
```

So now I have used a dictionary and It is working for the most part, but I am getting and error

keyerror: '%'

Comment: Why not make a dictionary of the mappings?

Comment: @ Edgar Aroutiounian because I tried it and couldn't get it work and I was told since we weren't taught about dictionaries yet, there would be a chance I could lose marks

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is threefold:

1. You always use the `1`th item from the `zip`ped lists, irrespective of the current character;
2. Each item is a two-tuple `(str , int)`; and
3. You do this once for every character in `letterlist` (never actually using your index `ii`).

Instead, use the index of one list to access the other for each letter in `name`:

```
code = 1
for c in name:
    code *= primes[letterlist.index(c)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am wondering the speed at which this will be able to calculate codes for about 16,000 words

Comment: How fast do you need to do it? It is `O(n)` to search `letterlist`. If speed is important, the dictionary approach would be much quicker (`O(1)`).

Comment: within a minute, but i left it for 5mins and nothing

Comment: It shouldn't take that long. Test the code function on one word, then test the bit that works through the words with a smaller set.

Comment: I did, I tried 30 words and it went fine. My prof said I can use dictionaries without lose of marks. Which is easier to apply, but I am getting KeyError: '%'

Comment: Yeah, your code only deals with characters a-z. You will need to either `try: except KeyError` or check `if key in d:` first.

Answer (score 1):

You can make dict and use [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) for multiply:

```
>>> d = dict(zip(letterlist, primes))
>>> d
{'a': 2, 'c': 5, 'b': 3, 'e': 11, 'd': 7, 'g': 17, 'f': 13, 'i': 23, 'h': 19,
 'k': 31, 'j': 29, 'm': 41, 'l': 37, 'o': 47, 'n': 43, 'q': 59, 'p': 53, 's': 67,
 'r': 61, 'u': 73, 't': 71, 'w': 83, 'v': 79, 'y': 97, 'x': 89, 'z': 101}

>>> reduce(lambda i, p: i*p, [d[c] for c in name])
409760241
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what jonrsharpe posted is what I needed since I am not supposed to use dictionaries.